# Deleting all but last 5 min of data

Tags: sqlite, datetime

I am trying to delete entries over 5 min old. Looking at [SQLite's datetime function](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_datefunc.html) I attempted :

```
DELETE FROM MyTable WHERE TimeStamp < datetime('now', '-5 minutes')
```

This erases all data however, not just last 5 mins. When using a datetime object (`toString()`) it does nothing. Does anyone have a solution?

Comment: What is the type of your TimeStamp column?

Comment: @vache - it is a datetime. A solution has been found however :D I simply subtract the 5 mins from the datetime then pass it, rather than using SQL, I would still be interested to know why the above does not work however :P

Comment: Have you tried using SELECT date('now') on your DB, perhaps the time is wrong ?

Comment: I have, the time seems to be ok.

Comment: What do you get with `SELECT TimeStamp, datetime('now', '-5 minutes') FROM MyTable WHERE TimeStamp < datetime('now', '-5 minutes')`